# Integration testing in VS2012 - how to manage test database?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I need to start integration testing the areas of my BLL where data access is involved, and I'm wondering about the best way to manage a test database (which needs to be separate from my day-to-day development database). I could manage such a database manually, remembering to refresh it whenever the schema changed, but it feels like there must be a slicker solution.

My solution includes a unit test project, and a SQL Server database project. As I'm using EF5 (database first), could I use the context to create a database during `[TestInitialise]`, or is this only supported by "code first"? What about (somehow) utilising the database project's "publish" feature to create a test database when starting a test run? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use transactions on your test or staging database? 
I often start a transaction in my setup:

```
     [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew);
        }
```

Then dispose it in the teardown:

```
   [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _transactionScope.Dispose();
        }
```

In some cases for me, this alleviates the need for an extra database.

Comment: I think of transactions as being just for "write" operations, and hadn't considered that I could first write the data out then read it back (to verify what had been written), in a single transaction. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yep - I use it that way for integration testing. I find that technique really handy when I think there might be some problem in my data layer. I write some expected test data - run my tests to assert that data is handled how I expect, then let the transaction clean the test data out so I don't trash my database.